# Javascript check multidimensional array if keys exists

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hello I need to check 3 - dimensional json array, now I check it like this

```
if(events[dd][mm][rr] !== undefined){}
```

but if keys doesn't exists it throw's me an error. `TypeError: events[dd] is undefined`

I need some JS function to check if this condition is exists and throught error of TypeError. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to check for each nested namespace. You could also write a recursive function if needed, if you have to check deeper into the map later on.

```
if (events[dd] && events[dd][mm] && events[dd][mm][rr] !== undefined) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use something like this:

```
function mdArrayExists(arr, var_args) {
    for (var i=1, k=arguments.length; i<k; ++i) {
        if (!arr || !arr.hasOwnProperty(arguments[i])
            return false;
        arr = arr[arguments[i]];
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
if (mdArrayExists(events, dd, mm, rr) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no affiliation with this company, but whenever I need to do Array Searching work I use the [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) library for doing it, because it has a bunch of functions for finding data quickly, and performance wise seems to be better about overhead then if I have to iterate over arrays myself.